# Changing properly value of objects in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm a newbie on ReactJS and I'm currently working on a project with cards similar to those on the link provided. Cards with `isFavorite` value set to `true` should appear when **FAVORITE** button is clicked. My question is, how do I change the property value of `isFavorite` to `true` or `false` when I click on the **Favorite** button on each card?

Code on the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cards-kgyzvc?file=/src/App.js

data.js

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    text:
      "So you two dig up, dig up dinosaurs? Yeah, but your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn't stop to think if they should. You know what? It is beets. I've crashed into a beet truck. You know what? It is beets. I've crashed into a beet truck.",
    isFavorite: true
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    text:
      "I gave it a cold? I gave it a virus. A computer virus. Hey, take a look at the earthlings. Goodbye! Eventually, you do plan to have dinosaurs on your dinosaur tour, right? This thing comes fully loaded. AM/FM radio, reclining bucket seats, and... power windows.",
    isFavorite: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text:
      "Remind me to thank John for a lovely weekend. They're using our own satellites against us. And the clock is ticking. Jaguar shark! So tell me - does it really exist? Remind me to thank John for a lovely weekend. Checkmate... Yeah, but John, if The Pirates of the Caribbean breaks down, the pirates don’t eat the tourists.",
    isFavorite: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text:
      "Just my luck, no ice. Eventually, you do plan to have dinosaurs on your dinosaur tour, right? Yeah, but John, if The Pirates of the Caribbean breaks down, the pirates don’t eat the tourists. Remind me to thank John for a lovely weekend. We gotta burn the rain forest, dump toxic waste, pollute the air, and rip up the OZONE! 'Cause maybe if we screw up this planet enough, they won't want it anymore!",
    isFavorite: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text:
      "I was part of something special. Hey, you know how I'm, like, always trying to save the planet? Here's my chance. Eventually, you do plan to have dinosaurs on your dinosaur tour, right? Hey, take a look at the earthlings. Goodbye! I was part of something special.",
    isFavorite: false
  }
];

export default data;
```

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [all, setAll] = useState(true);
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(false);

  const showAll = () => {
    setAll(true);
    setFavorites(false);
  };
  const showFavorite = () => {
    setFavorites(true);
    setAll(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="button-group">
        <button className={all ? "all active" : "all"} onClick={showAll}>
          ALL
        </button>
        <button
          className={favorites ? "favorites active" : "favorites"}
          onClick={showFavorite}
        >
          FAVORITES
        </button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <Masonry
        breakpointCols={3}
        className="my-masonry-grid"
        columnClassName="my-masonry-grid_column"
      >
        {all &&
          data.map((item) => (
            <Cards
              key={item.id}
              text={item.text}
              isFavorite={item.isFavorite}
            />
          ))}
        {favorites &&
          data
            .filter((item) => item.isFavorite === true)
            .map((filtered) => (
              <Cards
                key={filtered.id}
                text={filtered.text}
                isFavorite={filtered.isFavorite}
              />
            ))}
      </Masonry>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Cards.js

```
const Cards = ({ text, isFavorite }) => {
  return (
    <div className="cards">
      <p>{text}</p>
      <button>{isFavorite ? "Added to Favorites!" : "Favorite"}</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please include the code in the question itself, an external link is fine in addition to the relevant code, but shouldn't be the only way to see it. (Otherwise any changes to that external site could prevent this question being useful to other readers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your code, **I made a fork with explanations on how to handle this case.**

**In a few words:**

First you have to copy and have a local state of this dataSource, so you can modify it.

```js
const [dataSource,setDataSource] = useState(data)
```

Then we have to add a new property to your Cards component, we have to detect the click on the favorite button of the utility to be able to modify the object in our dataSource.

```js
const Cards = ({ text, isFavorite, onClick }) => {
...
  <button onClick={onClick}>
    {isFavorite ? "Added to Favorites!" : "Favorite"}
  </button>
...
```

Finally we have a function inside the App.js that handles the click on a Card component and can update the dataSource state.

```js
  /**
   * This function will handle the click on the button favorite
   * on each card item
   * @param {number} cardId
   */
  const onFavorite = (cardId) => {
    // We can find with the id of the card, the data associated in our dataSource

    // First we need to copy the old dataSource, because we cannot update directly the dataSource state
    const newDataSource = [...dataSource];

    // Now we need to find the data associated to the id of the card
    const foundCardData = newDataSource.find((card) => card.id === cardId);

    if (!foundCardData) {
      // If we do not have the card we can return and the function will stop here
      return;
    }

    // Now we can update the card object
    foundCardData.isFavorite = !foundCardData.isFavorite;

    // Finally we can update the dataSource state with the newDataSource that contains the updated object
    setDataSource(newDataSource);
  };
```

> You can find the solution here with comments :
> https://codesandbox.io/s/cards-forked-htt9d6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I checked the code on the sandbox. It seems that the card buttons don't toggle from "Favorite" to "Added to favorites" when they're appearing under **FAVORITES**. Is there any way to fix that? EDIT: Fixed it. I just added an onClick on it. Thank you for this!

Comment: Yes I gave you the freedom to do it as an example haha

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to add a new state to keep your data

```
const [dataState, setDataState] = useState(data);
```

And then add another function called `switchFavorite` (the name can be changed at your choice) to update data state with favorite changes

```
const switchFavorite = (cardId, favoriteValue) => {
    setDataState(
      dataState.map((card) =>
        card.id === cardId
          ? {
              ...card,
              isFavorite: favoriteValue
            }
          : card
      )
    );
  };
```

Don't forget to add `switchFavorite` along with `id` (card id) to `Cards` props which are to handle favorite clicks in `Card`s component

```
<Cards
   key={filtered.id}
   text={filtered.text}
   isFavorite={filtered.isFavorite}
   id={filtered.id}
   switchFavorite={switchFavorite}
/>
```

Full code for `App`

```js
import "./styles.css";
import data from "./data";
import Cards from "./Cards";
import Masonry from "react-masonry-css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [all, setAll] = useState(true);
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(false);
  const [dataState, setDataState] = useState(data);

  const showAll = () => {
    setAll(true);
    setFavorites(false);
  };
  const showFavorite = () => {
    setFavorites(true);
    setAll(false);
  };

  const switchFavorite = (cardId, favoriteValue) => {
    setDataState(
      dataState.map((card) =>
        card.id === cardId
          ? {
              ...card,
              isFavorite: favoriteValue
            }
          : card
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="button-group">
        <button className={all ? "all active" : "all"} onClick={showAll}>
          ALL
        </button>
        <button
          className={favorites ? "favorites active" : "favorites"}
          onClick={showFavorite}
        >
          FAVORITES
        </button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <Masonry
        breakpointCols={3}
        className="my-masonry-grid"
        columnClassName="my-masonry-grid_column"
      >
        {all &&
          dataState.map((item) => (
            <Cards
              key={item.id}
              text={item.text}
              isFavorite={item.isFavorite}
              id={item.id}
              switchFavorite={switchFavorite}
            />
          ))}
        {favorites &&
          dataState
            .filter((item) => item.isFavorite === true)
            .map((filtered) => (
              <Cards
                key={filtered.id}
                text={filtered.text}
                isFavorite={filtered.isFavorite}
                id={filtered.id}
                switchFavorite={switchFavorite}
              />
            ))}
      </Masonry>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The final piece is applying `onClick` on favorite button in `Cards`

```
const Cards = ({ text, id, isFavorite, switchFavorite }) => {
  return (
    <div className="cards">
      <p>{text}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          switchFavorite(id, !isFavorite);
        }}
      >
        {isFavorite ? "Added to Favorites!" : "Favorite"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[The sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cards-forked-n904n1?file=/src/App.js)